# Which is the sybase driver(version) to be used in Weblogic 12c ? Where should I add the downloaded driver?

Tags: java, jdbc, weblogic, weblogic12c

I am migrating my application from Weblogic 9 to 12c.

The connection pool - **cvSybasepool** created for my application is working fine on Web logic 9.
I had used **com.sybase.jdbc.SybDriver** to connect to **Sybase** database on Weblogic 9.

After replicating the connection pool(cvSybasepool) on Weblogic 12c, I get the following error:

```
<Jun 21, 2016 4:40:25 AM EDT> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149205> <Failed to initialize the application "cvSybasepool" due to error weblogic.application.ModuleException: weblogic.com
mon.resourcepool.ResourceSystemException: Cannot load driver class com.sybase.jdbc.SybDriver for datasource 'cvSybasepool'.
weblogic.application.ModuleException: weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourceSystemException: Cannot load driver class com.sybase.jdbc.SybDriver for datasource 'cvSybasepool'.
        at weblogic.jdbc.module.JDBCModule.prepare(JDBCModule.java:350)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:175)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:170)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourceSystemException: Cannot load driver class com.sybase.jdbc.SybDriver for datasource 'cvSybasepool'.
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.JDBCUtil.parseException(JDBCUtil.java:322)
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionEnvFactory.loadDriver(ConnectionEnvFactory.java:82)
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionEnvFactory.<init>(ConnectionEnvFactory.java:141)
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionPool.initPooledResourceFactory(ConnectionPool.java:1110)
        at weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourcePoolImpl.start(ResourcePoolImpl.java:226)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

I suspect the Sybase JDBC driver jar is missing on Web logic 12c.

Also, When the Sybase driver provided by Web logic server is used, I get the following error

```
FILogger.log(232) - java.sql.SQLException: [FMWGEN][Sybase JDBC Driver][Sybase]A USE DATABASE statement is not allowed in a procedure or trigger. at weblogic.jdbc.sybasebase.ddcn.b(Unknown Source) at weblogic.jdbc.sybasebase.ddcn.a(Unknown Source) at weblogic.jdbc.sybasebase.ddcm.b(Unknown Source) at weblogic.jdbc.sybasebase.ddcm.a(Unknown Source)
```

1. Which driver needs to be used to connect to Sybase DB on Weblogic
   12c? Jconn2.jar/Jconn3.jar?
2. Which jar needs to be added to Weblogic server?
3. Where do I need to add the jar and what configuration has be done?

Comment: Can anyone please let me know where(which folder) I have to add the jdbc jar downloaded in web logic server & configure it for use in data source?

Comment: I have downloaded the jconn3.jar. May I know where to add this jar and configure it for use in data source?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally resolved the issue.

I could not use the sybase driver(weblogic.jdbc.sybase.SybaseDriver) bundled with weblogic as it was not complaint with my SQL code

Below are steps I followed.

1. Downloaded & copied JDBC driver JAR - jConnect.jar to
   ${WL_HOME}/server/lib/
2. Updated the setDomainEnv.cmd script in my domain's bin directory,
   and prepended the JAR file to the PRE_CLASSPATH environment
   variable(If the newly added JDBC driver JAR is required in other
   domains, then edit the commEnv.cmd/sh script in WL_HOME/common/bin
   and prepend your JAR file to the WEBLOGIC_CLASSPATH environment
   variable.)
3. Restarted the server.

Answer (score 3):

Update or re-create your datasource to use the sybase driver available with weblogic server 12c (weblogic.jdbc.sybase.SybaseDriver)

Comment: After updating the data source, I get this error                                     <Jun 21, 2016 7:18:58 AM EDT> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149205> <Failed to initialize the application "cvSybasepool" due to error weblogic.application.ModuleException: weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourceSystemException: The driver weblogic.jdbc.sybase.SybaseDriver does not accept URL jdbc:sybase:Tds:CVDB_DEV:12000/tt
weblogic.application.ModuleException: weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourceSystemException: The driver weblogic.jdbc.sybase.SybaseDriver does not accept URL jdbc:sybase:Tds:CVDB_DEV:12000/tt

Comment: Check your url format. Should be like this : jdbc:weblogic:sybase://hostname:port[;property=value[;...]]

Comment: I updated the URL format. Now I get the below error when I run the application -                                                                                             21 08:27:06  FILogger.log(232) - java.sql.SQLException: [FMWGEN][Sybase JDBC Driver][Sybase]A USE DATABASE statement is not allowed in a procedure or trigger.

       at weblogic.jdbc.sybasebase.ddcn.b(Unknown Source)
       at weblogic.jdbc.sybasebase.ddcn.a(Unknown Source)
       at weblogic.jdbc.sybasebase.ddcm.b(Unknown Source)
       at weblogic.jdbc.sybasebase.ddcm.a(Unknown Source)

Comment: your connection is ok, but the sql code is not. Driver issue which is not compliant with your sql code. You should download and install last jdbc driver from sybase instead of using ones provided by weblogic

Comment: Thanks for your answers. May I know where do I need to add the jars downloaded and what configuration has to be done in weblogic?

Comment: Jars must be added to your server's classpath (server restart required). Next, update your datasource to use your new jdbc driver class and the new url format

Comment: Is {WEBLOGIC_HOME}/wlserver/server/lib the class path for server. Do I need to add the jar at this location & restart the server? Or do I need to add the jars to {WEBLOGIC_HOME}/wlserver/server/ext folder?

Comment: If you do so all your domains will be able to use this driver.
Put your jar in {WEBLOGIC_HOME}/wlserver/server/lib and restart your server.